# loading animation appears above of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a project.in  that project i need a loading animation. So i created one. but the problem is i can't hide the scroll bar. if i give overflow hidden to my body by css and when loading animation finished i gave overflow auto by js. it will create another problem. (.inner-menus goes down of .puller. and it doesn't goes left properly, it takes space of scroll bar.)the reason I detected: when window loads there is no scroll bar and js take window width and minus .puller width from window width and set the value as .inner-menu width and there is no window's scroll bar width.(chrome scrollbar width is 17px.but other browser's scroll bar width is nor 17px) . if i go full page it just OK because it re take window width and minus .puller width from window width and set the value as .inner-menu width(this time there is scroll bar).
so i just want that the animation div goes overly scroll. Is it possible? if not please try to give another solution.

thanks

without body overflow hidden.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loaderBg").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
})
$(document).ready(function() {
   
  var calcWidth = function() {
  var pullerDimensions = $('.puller').width();
   $('.inner-menu').width($(window).width() - (pullerDimensions +2));
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
   calcWidth();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
   calcWidth();
  }).load(function() {
   calcWidth();
  });
  
  
    (function($) {
   $(".puller").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".menu").css("left") == "0px") {
     $(".menu").stop().animate({
      left: -1 * $(window).width() + 50
     }, 'slow');
    } else {
     $(".menu").stop().animate({
      left: 0
     }, 'slow');
    }
   });

   $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    $(".menu").css("width", width);

    if ($(".menu").css("left") != "0px") {
     $(".menu").css("left", (-1 * $(window).width() + 50));
    }
   });
  }(jQuery));
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    background: #3F51B5;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: arial;
}
.content {
    height: 200vh;
}
.menu {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: calc(-100% + 49px);
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A09E9E;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    height: 150px;
}
.loaderBg {
    height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
    background: #333;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.puller {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #A09E9E;
    border-right: 1px solid #A09E9E;
    left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
  cursor: hidden;
}
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  width: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
}
.loader:before {
  left: -1.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader {
  text-indent: -9999em;
  margin: 88px auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:after {
  left: 1.5em;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 #ffffff;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em #ffffff;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
@keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 #ffffff;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em #ffffff;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loaderBg">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="inner-menu">
      menu item-1<br>
      menu item-2
    </div>
    <div class="puller">
      &gt;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With overflow hidden

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loaderBg").delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
      $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    });
})
$(document).ready(function() {
   
  var calcWidth = function() {
  var pullerDimensions = $('.puller').width();
   $('.inner-menu').width($(window).width() - (pullerDimensions +2));
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
   calcWidth();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
   calcWidth();
  }).load(function() {
   calcWidth();
  });
  
  
    (function($) {
   $(".puller").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".menu").css("left") == "0px") {
     $(".menu").stop().animate({
      left: -1 * $(window).width() + 50
     }, 'slow');
    } else {
     $(".menu").stop().animate({
      left: 0
     }, 'slow');
    }
   });

   $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    $(".menu").css("width", width);

    if ($(".menu").css("left") != "0px") {
     $(".menu").css("left", (-1 * $(window).width() + 50));
    }
   });
  }(jQuery));
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    background: #3F51B5;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: arial;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    height: 200vh;
}
.menu {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: calc(-100% + 49px);
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A09E9E;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    height: 150px;
}
.loaderBg {
    height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
    background: #333;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.puller {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #A09E9E;
    border-right: 1px solid #A09E9E;
    left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
  cursor: hidden;
}
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load1 1s infinite ease-in-out;
  width: 1em;
  height: 4em;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
}
.loader:before {
  left: -1.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader {
  text-indent: -9999em;
  margin: 88px auto;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 11px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:after {
  left: 1.5em;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 #ffffff;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em #ffffff;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
@keyframes load1 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 #ffffff;
    height: 4em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 -2em #ffffff;
    height: 5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loaderBg">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="inner-menu">
      menu item-1<br>
      menu item-2
    </div>
    <div class="puller">
      &gt;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, you can't place a div *over* a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Make this change in your JS.

```js
var calcWidth; // declare calc width as global
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".loaderBg").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $("body").css("overflow","auto");
        calcWidth(); // call here
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   
  calcWidth = function() {
  var pullerDimensions = $('.puller').width();
   $('.inner-menu').width($(window).width() - (pullerDimensions +2));
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
   calcWidth();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
   calcWidth();
  }).load(function() {
   calcWidth();
  });
  
  
    (function($) {
   $(".puller").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".menu").css("left") == "0px") {
     $(".menu").stop().animate({
      left: -1 * $(window).width() + 50
     }, 'slow');
    } else {
     $(".menu").stop().animate({
      left: 0
     }, 'slow');
    }
   });

   $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();

    $(".menu").css("width", width);

    if ($(".menu").css("left") != "0px") {
     $(".menu").css("left", (-1 * $(window).width() + 50));
    }
   });
  }(jQuery));
});
```